# IBM Mobilefirst 7.0- Barcode Scanner for Hybrid App is not working

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

Here I'm trying to build an Hybrid Application using IBM Mobilefirst, In which I want to use Barcode Scanner. For this I followed the following link.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/WASFAQs/entry/using_a_barcode_scanner_with_worklight?lang=en

And, here is My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Barcode</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
        <!--
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
        -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
<script>
$('#scanButton').bind('click', doScan);
function doScan(){
alert("Hello");
alert(cordova.exec(onScanSuccess, onScanFailure, 'BarcodeScanner', 'scan', []));
}
function onScanSuccess(result) {
alert("We got a barcode\n" +
    "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
    "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
    "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
}
function onScanFailure(error) {
alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body style="display: none;">
        <!--application UI goes here-->
        <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        <h1>Barcode scanner</h1>
        <button type="button" id="scanButton" >Scan</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you can't be bothered to explain HOW this isn't working, we can't be bothered to try and GUESS at what the problem might be.

Comment: When I click on Scan button then the doScan function is calling, Inside of doScan cordova.exex() is not calling and not showing any error also

Comment: you define doScan **AFTER** you try to do the bind, which means doScan hasn't been defined yet, and you're binding to a non-existent function. If you'd done even basic debugging: opening the JS console, you'd have seen that error. it'll have killed the rest of the JS code block

Comment: Previously I tried by using onclick function. In that case also it's not working

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for cordova.exec to fail would be if you wrongly configured the  config.xml with the plug-in reference.

You did not add the LogCat log to your question - there you'd see the actual error you're facing.